# Not hitting debugger in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am currently having some difficulty hitting my third debugger breakpoint in my Javascript, Rails, JQuery application. It hits the first two just fine, but is not hitting the third. Does anyone see why this might be the case? Thanks in advance! Here is the code that I am working with:

user_index.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".loadCars").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
        var url = this.href
    debugger
    $.getJSON(url)
    .success(function(data) {
        $('#cars').html("");
      debugger
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            var newCar = new Car(value, url);

            var carHtml = newCar.formatDisplay();
              $('#cars').append(carHtml)

        debugger
            });

      });
    });
});

function Car(car, url) {
    this.id = car.id
    this.make = car.make
    this.model = car.model

    this.awards = car.awards
};

Car.prototype.formatDisplay = function() {
    var awardsHtml = ""
    $.each(this.awards,function() {
        var awardListItem = this.formatDisplay()
        awardsHtml += awardListItem
    });
    var carHtml = `<div><a href='${this.carUrl}'>${this.make} + " " + ${this.model} </a></div>
                                            <div>Awards:</div>
                                            <ul>${awardsHtml}</ul>`;
    return carHtml;
};

function Award(award) {
    this.id = award.id
    this.title = award.title
    this.description = award.description
};

Award.prototype.formatDisplay = function() {
    var awardHtml = `<li>Award: ${this.title}, Description: ${this.description}</li>`
    return awardHtml;
};
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @cars = @user.cars
  end

  def destroy
    session.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def cars_index
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @cars = @user.cars
    render template: 'cars/all'
  end

  def car_index
    @user = current_user
    @cars = @user.cars
    render json: @cars
  end

end
```

users/show.html.erb

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<h1>My Profile:</h1>
<h1><%= @user.email %></h1><br>

<button class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to "Load Cars", car_index_path(@user), :class => "loadCars" %></button><br><br>

<div class="cars">
  <ol>

  </ol>
</div>

<div id="cars">
  <ol>

  </ol>
</div>
```

Please let me know if there are any other code snippets that would be helpful in diagnosing the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried making the debugger the first statement in the each?

Comment: Hi @Taplar thanks for taking a look! I had not tried that yet, and it definitely helped me zone in on the problem! It looks like the error is coming in when I hit the formatDisplay function within the Car.prototype.formatDisplay function. Do you know why I might be hitting an error there? I am pretty new to this so I appreciate the help!

Comment: It looks like you are expecting `this.awards` to be Car objects?  Are they?  You can throw debugger statements in there too, :)

Comment: Also `${this.make} + " " + ${this.model}` looks kinda weird since you are inside ``

Comment: Gotcha, I put a debugger in Car.protoype.formatDisplay, and each iteration of the each is being called on an award object. I define my formatDisplay for the award objects below, so I am wondering why I am getting the this.formatDisplay() is not a function error. Do you have any idea why that may be the case? Thanks again!

Comment: `data` is coming from the request response, so it's not a Car object.  You are looping over it.  You create a `new Car(value, url);` with value, which is not a Car object.  The constructor takes that `value` in as `car` and sets the `this.awards = car.awards`.  `car.awards`, coming from the `value` variable, will not be Car objects.  So when you later loop over the awards on the element, and try to do `this.formatDisplay()` on each award, those awards are not Car objects.  Agreed?

Comment: When I put the debugger at the end of the car constructor, it is returning the intended results. car.awards is an array of award objects, car is a car object. I may be misunderstanding your response, in which case I apologize, but shouldn't the each inside of car.prototype.display() work if it is iterating over this.awards, since that is an array of award objects?

Comment: Actually i missed the formatDisplay on the Award object.  So now the question is where are you turning the `car.awards` into Award objects?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I just assumed that happened automatically. When the awards are created, they are created as award objects associated with the car. Is there another place that I should/can define them as award objects?

Comment: I would assume you would do the converting as part of the Car constructor.  Mapping the car.awards to Award objects.

Comment: Ok, what syntax would you suggest using there? Sorry, pretty new to this so not sure how exactly to pull that off. Really appreciate the help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the awards are not Award objects.  You'll want to create Award objects to access those methods, like you do with Car objects.

```
function Car(car, url) {
    this.id = car.id;
    this.make = car.make;
    this.model = car.model;

    if (car.awards) {
        this.awards = car.awards.map(award => new Award(award));
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad we found your problem, :)